# Level set of a continuous function strictly increasing in each argument

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $F : \mathbb{R}^d \to [0,1]$ be absolutely continuous and strictly increasing in each argument. Is it true that the boundary of the set $\{ \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d: F(x) \geq \alpha \}$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is equal to the $\alpha$-level set of $F$, i.e. to the set $\{ \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d: F(x) = \alpha \}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can prove much more general topological fact. Let $X$ be a topological space and $F:X\to\Bbb R$ be a continuous function without local minima, $\alpha\in\Bbb R$, $A=\{x\in X: F(x) \geq \alpha \}$,  and $B=\{x\in X: F(x) =\alpha \}$. Then $\partial A=B$. Indeed, since the function $F$ is continuous the sets $A=F^{-1}[\alpha,\infty)$  and $B=F^{-1}(\alpha)$ are closed. By definition, $\partial A=\overline{A}\setminus\operatorname{int} A=A\setminus\operatorname{int} A $. Let $x\in B$ be an arbitrary point and $O_x$ be an arbitrary neighborhood of the point $x$. Since the function $F$ has no local minima, there exists a point $y\in O_x$ such that $F(y)<F(x)=\alpha$. Therefore $y\not\in A$ and so $x$ is not an interior point of the set $A$. Thus $B\subset A\setminus\operatorname{int} A=\partial A$. Conversely, let $x\in\partial A$ be an arbitrary point. Suppose that $F(x)>\alpha$. Since the function $F$ is continuous, there exists an open neighborhood $O_x$ of the point $x$ such that $F(y)>\alpha$ for each point $y\in O_x$. Then $x\in O_x\subset\operatorname{int} A$. But $\partial A\cap\operatorname{int} A=\varnothing,$ a contradiction. Hence $F(x)=\alpha$, and thus $x\in B$.

Comment: This is not correct at the time of writing but can be made so by switching max to min and < to >. I tried to edit but was rejected with "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner." This is stupid. It is only possible to argue that I did not preserve the post owner's goal if his goal was to get it wrong.

Comment: @Ali I agree with your remarks. Thanks.