# Can one show that the solution to this elliptic PDE is a decreasing function?

Tags: monotone-functions, elliptic-equations, linear-pde

Assume $\boldsymbol{g}:\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}\to [0,1]^{n}$ and
$\boldsymbol{h}:\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ continuous functions, and that if I know $\boldsymbol{g}$ to be decreasing* then I can deduce $\boldsymbol{h}$ strictly increasing.
Now let
$V=\left\{\boldsymbol{y}\in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}\mid \forall i\quad 0<h_{i}(\boldsymbol{y})\right\}$
and solve for each $f_{i}$ with
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{cases}
    Lf_{i}=0&\text{ in }V\\
    f_{i} = g_{i}&\text{ on }\partial V.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Assume $S$ a constant, positive definite $n\times n$ matrix and
\begin{equation*}
  Lf=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{jk}S_{jk}\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial y_{j}\partial y_{k}}
  +\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j}S_{jj}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_{j}}+f.
\end{equation*}
My intuition is that if $\boldsymbol{g}$ is in fact decreasing then so is $\boldsymbol{f}$. Is it true?

*If $x_{i}\leq y_{i}$ for all $i$ then
$g_{i}(\boldsymbol{x})\geq g_{i}(\boldsymbol{y})$ for all $i$.

**Background**
I am trying to build a system of functions inductively. Each successive function is determined by solving the PDE using boundary conditions prescribed by previous solutions. If I can show by induction that all these functions are decreasing, then I can claim something about boundaries being uniquely determined and the system of functions being uniquely determined. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091687/) SE question is relevant.

**What have I done?**
I have been reading in Evans about various maximum principles. But even if I could show that $f_{i}$ has no minimum in the interior of $V$, I don't think it would be enough for the induction... Edit: just realised that Evans assumes bounded domains everywhere :(

Even just a good book recommendation would be welcome!